# How to create case in-sensitive associative array in AWK

Tags: bash, awk, associative-array

I am trying to create associative array but it is case sensitive. Is there any command from i can create case in-sensitive associative array in Awk.

Answer (score 1):

Use `tolower()` when storing into the array:

```
arr[tolower($1)] = $2
```

and when looking something up in it:

```
print arr[tolower($3)]
```